# jQuery Datatable plugin not filtering on Column value

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin for my application. The data is a static HTML data as in the JsFiddle shared below. On clicking a button the data needs to be filtered and displayed in the table.

I have tried to filter on the `Software Engineer` string on the `Position` column of the table using the [Datatables Filtering API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter%28%29), but without success.

Please find the JsFiddle link below.

[Datatables Filter Functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/SphinX/0oya4h64/)

**Javascript, CSS & HTML below**

```js
$(function() {

  var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    lengthChange: false
  });

  $('#filterButton').on('click', function() {
    var filterText = 'Software Engineer';

    dataTable.column(1)
      .data()
      .filter(function(value, index) {
        console.log(value + ' : ' + filterText)
        if (value == filterText) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
  });

});
```

```css
.btn {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<button id="filterButton" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
<table id="example" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I took a look at [Custom filtering - range search](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html), in the Datatables example and could modify it to my requirement.

```
$(function () {

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        if (data[1] == 'Software Engineer') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    var exampledDataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        searching: false,
        info: false,
        lengthChange: false
    });

    $('#filterButton').on('click', function () {
        exampledDataTable.draw();
    });

});
```

I was not able to get it to work on JsFiddle, hence have pasted only the snippet here.

This code is filtering based on the string `Software Engineer` that is hardcoded in the `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$(function () {
    var dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        searching: true,
        info: false,
        lengthChange: false
    });
    $('#filterButton').on('click', function () {
        dataTable.draw();
    });
});
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var target = 'Software Engineer';
        var position = data[1]; // use data for the age column
        if (target === position){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/ay16vnp1/